# How to install packages correctly using yarn?

Tags: reactjs, package, frontend, yarnpkg

I built a react App with a tutorial using react-redux (with node.js).
Now im trying to import the code in a pre-build react app to get my list of Products from My DB.
When i try to import the code i get the following error, because it isn't installed:

```
./src/container/Home/Grid/LuxaryHotelsGrid.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-redux' in 'C:\Users\Andre\Desktop\bookingapp\React Template\QuickFinder\packages\hotel\src\container\Home\Grid'
```

Where should i Install my react-redux package? The pre-build app uses yarn.
I read that it shouldn't be installed globally. But i dont want to install it in every component where i need it either. What is the best solution?

Comment: Run a command `yarn add react-redux` in your root folder of your project.

Comment: i installed it in C:\Users\Andre\Desktop\bookingapp\React Template.
now i get the following error:

C:/Users/Andre/Desktop/bookingapp/React Template/QuickFinder/node_modules/react-redux/es/connect/mapDispatchToProps.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'redux' in 'C:\Users\Andre\Desktop\bookingapp\ ReactTemplate\QuickFinder\node_modules\react-redux\es\connect'

Comment: solved it. I had to add "redux" too

Comment: Good job. However `react-redux` has `redux` as a dependency.